# find number of elements with same custom attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a table with multiple rows having a common custom attribute prId . How can i find out no. of rows with same custom attribute. i can not use jquery

```
<tr id="mainRow2" prId = "2"></tr>
<tr id="subRow2_1" prId = "2"></tr>
<tr id="subRow2_2" prId = "2"></tr>
<tr id="subRow2_3" prId = "2"></tr>
<tr id="mainRow5" prId = "5"></tr>
<tr id="subRow5_1" prId = "5"></tr>
<tr id="subRow5_2" prId = "5"></tr>
<tr id="subRow5_3" prId = "5"></tr>
<tr id="subRow5_4" prId = "5"></tr>
```

Comment: USe querySelectorAll()

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[prId='" + 2 + "']").length
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTD/3/

Answer (score 1):

Without using query selector (which is better, but less supported) as shown above, you could use

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), tr, i, count = 0;

for (i = 0; ( tr = trs[i] ); i += 1) {
    // use your own attribute value here, of course
    if (tr.getAttribute('prId') === '2') {
        count += 1;
    }
}

alert(count + ' prIds counted.');
```